# Use SQL Server as Subscriber PostgreSQL as publisher

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-10, change-data-capture

I have a rather large PostgreSQl database.
This server is set up as a publisher.
Now I want to set up MSSQL server as a subscriber to this publisher, is that possible?

PostgreSQL = 10.4 
MSSQL = 2017

Comment: Have a look at https://debezium.io/ or http://www.symmetricds.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DBsync is a solution that is simple to implement but does it's work good for a low price